# Do the lowered level parameters for selecting a Wild Cohort Extend to its Bonus HD/Nat Armor/Tricks?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, feats, druid

For referencer the feat can be found [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20210217062407/http://archive.wizards.com/default.asp?x=dnd/re/20031118a) I was wondering, the feat when it says

"When selecting an alternative animal cohort, use the list of alternative animal companions on page 36 of the Player's Handbook, but treat yourself as a druid three levels lower than your character level. For example, once you reach 7th level, you can choose an animal cohort off the list of animal companions available to a 4th-level druid."

unlike the druid entry for its Animal Companion Feature it does not say

"Should she select an animal companion from one of these alternative lists, the creature gains abilities as if the character’s druid level were lower than it actually is. Subtract the value indicated in the appropriate list header from the character’s druid level and compare the result with the druid level entry on the table to determine the animal companion’s powers."

My question is even if it doesnt say does this rule apply to the wild cohort?

Even if the answer is no the companion gained through Wild Cohort doesnt advance as quickly nor does it qualify for Animal Companion Feats. I just had to ask after a disagreement with a group member about how to interperate this feat.

Comment: as far as Ive read the feat only applies that adjustment of level -3 when selecting a Wild Cohort. I could be wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct that the rules as written do not include that proviso; as written, there is no disadvantage to selecting a more powerful Wild Cohort, assuming you have a level high enough to do so.

This *does* seem odd, considering the druid’s and ranger’s rules. I *suspect* it was an oversight.

Overall, my main concern is this: it is possible, under this reading, for two characters of the same level, one with Wild Cohort and the other a druid, to choose the same animal, and for the Wild Cohort to wind up more powerful than the druid’s animal companion.

For example, suppose you and a druid are 13th level, and both select a dire lion. The druid’s dire lion gets the link and share spells features, and 1 bonus trick. He gains +2 HD, +2 Natural Armor, and +1 Strength and Dexterity bonuses. By your reading of Wild Cohort, however, your dire lion gains +7 HD, +7 natural armor, +3 Strength and Dexterity, 4 bonus tricks, and the evasion and devotion features.

It just seems wrong to me that the Wild Cohort would be better than the animal companion in these cases.

On the other hand, even if you apply that penalty to your effective character level, the Wild Cohort is still better than the ranger’s animal companion, and the druid is already more than powerful enough even if he doesn’t **have** an animal companion, so...

Comment: I suppose you are correct. quite a bit of a horrid oversight.

Comment: you also misread something. I could not if I had the feat take Dire Lion Until Level 13. Because on top of the -9 druid takes to obtain it I would take an additional -3

Comment: @Novian: OK, sure, so compare a Druid 13 to you at 13: he gets to add a little bit of stuff, but it's still not a lot.